# How to Execute an if statement inside another if statement

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to run if statement inside another if statement e.g. rough code

```
if (background-color = grey) {
return 
If (time >= 2.00) {
return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
}else if (time <=2.00){
return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'red', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');}
```

i cant seem to get the above to work.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and "it doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: You are using if statement with capital "I" !!! Really??

Comment: There are so many wrong things about this code, mostly on a syntactical level
 - It doesn't run, because it is not valid javascript. 
- 'background-color' isn't a variable name. It can't have dashes.
- You are assigning the backgroiund cololor instead of comparing it.
- reserved words are written in wrong case, which is illegal
- etc

You should try going through a basic programming class first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using an unnecessary return.
This should work.

---

```
if (background-color == grey) {
    if (time >= 2.00) {
        return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
    }else if (time <=2.00){
         return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'red', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider abstracting this out to a class.

Or you could do this:

```
if (background-color = grey) {
  border-color = time < 2 ? 'red': 'lime';

  var result = $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color': border-color, 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');

  return result
}
```